# Subselect in GQL syntax (Datastore viewer)

Tags: database, google-app-engine, syntax, gql, gqlquery

I have two entities: Cars (ownerId->String) and Users (userId->String), where ownerId is the foreign key representing userId.

I am trying to execute this Query, but I get "GQL syntax" at Datastore Viewer. How can I do this SUBSELECT?

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE ownerId IN (SELECT userId FROM Users);
```

Comment: You can't.  GQL is not SQL. You will need to to do one select, then iterate and fetch/filter or do two selects and merge in code. Alternately add a flag in the Car object that tells you that the Owner is a User, then you don't need to.

Comment: @Tim - you should make this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. GQL is not SQL.

You will need to to do one select, then iterate and fetch/filter or do two selects and merge in code.

Alternately add a flag in the Car object that tells you that the Owner is a User, then you don't need to

If you are not trying to write code, but just explore then the remote_api shell is a place to try these things.  Though this is much easier in python ;-)